# Copy row from excel worksheet to another if no match

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet ("All Documents") that is populated from a SharePoint list but also has some columns that contain formulas. I have another worksheet in the same workbook ("Original") that contains the original values of the list items. I need to compare the two worksheets and if the value in column A in "All Documents" does not exist in column A in "Original" it needs to copy the row to the "Original" sheet. It must be pasted as values. I have searched many forums and tried many suggestions but none worked. This is my latest attempt. Any assistance will be appreciated!

```
Dim x As Long, y As Long, a As Long
Dim b As String
Dim rFound As Range
Dim TargetRange As Range
x = Worksheets("All Documents").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For a = 2 To x
    y = Worksheets("Original").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    b = Worksheets("All Documents").Range("A" & a)
    If a > y Then Exit For
    With Worksheets("Original").Range("A:A")
        Set rFound = .Find(b, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If rFound Is Nothing Then
           TargetRange = Worksheets("Original"1).Cells(Worksheets("Original").Rows(y + 1))
           Worksheets("All Documents").Rows(a).Copy
           TargetRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    End With
Next a
```

Comment: whats not working about your code?

Comment: One thing that immediately caught my eye is this `TargetRange = Worksheets("Original"1)...` Should be `Set TargetRange = Worksheets("Original"1)....` Rest as @CAPSLOCK mentioned, let us know which part of the code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things,

1. To set a range you need to:

   ```
   Set TargetRange = Worksheets("Original").Rows(y + 1)
   ```
2. Check to see if the sheet is ment to be `"Original"1` or `"Original"`
3. And an improvement copy your values by:

   ```
   Worksheets("Original").Rows(y + 1).Value = _
     Worksheets("All Documents").Rows(a).Value
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  The 1 in ("Original"1) was a typo from when I copied the code in.  I tried suggestion in step 3 above and I am getting Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.   The value of y = 667, which is the number of rows in "Original".  The value of a = 104.  There are 730 rows in "All Documents". I tried it again and got Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.  I confirmed that both the destination sheet and the defined table is named "Original".  The source sheet is named "All Documents" but the defined table is "ALLDocuments".  Is that the problem?

Comment: Try now. Copying a row to a row, you shouldn't need the cells function.

Comment: That worked!   Thank you!!  Sorry about the delay in responding.  This is one of many projects.